# Typo3 11: Using QueryBuilder with REGEX_REPLACE

Tags: mysql, typo3, typo3-11.x

I have implemented a simple searchbar for my frontend plugin.
Now the text I am searching for is a rich text and contains html Tags inside the database field.

I found out that with a simple query condition like this, I can ignore the HTML tags and filter the text correctly:

```
WHERE REGEXP_REPLACE(a.content, '<[^>]*>', '') LIKE '%my search word%'
```

However, I didn't find an option for Typo3 Querybuilder and Expressionbuilder to do anything like this.

I tried to use REGEXP_REPLACE like this with the QueryBuilder:

```
)->orWhere(
                $queryBuilder->expr()->like(
                    $queryBuilder->expr()->literal("REGEXP_REPLACE(a.content, '<[^>]*>', '')", 0),
                    $queryBuilder->createNamedParameter('%' . $queryBuilder->escapeLikeWildcards($searchWord) . '%')
                )
            )
```

The query generated part by Typo3 looks like:

```
WHERE (`'REGEXP_REPLACE(a`.`content, \'<[^>]*>\', \'\')'` LIKE ?))
```

And this results in an unknown column error.

Comment: I would prefer to use $queryBuilder->add('where', 'REGEXP_REPLACE...LIKE...', true);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `add()` method of the QueryBuilder:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Database/QueryBuilder/Index.html#add

Your code should use:

```php
$queryBuilder->add('where', 'REGEXP_REPLACE(a.content, \'<[^>]*>\', \'\') LIKE \'%my search word%\'')
```